# What does this mean in C language

Tags: c

Consider the following code snippet:

```
for(lptr=str;*lptr !='\0';lptr++);
```

what is \0 here that's actually very confusing and what is the output?
and what happens here this snippet is the one I can't understand what are your opinions?
Cheers!

Comment: `'\0'` is the null character. The code loops through a C-string until its end.

Comment: `lptr=strchr(str, '\0');`

Comment: see [this](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: ' what is the output?'' - what happened when you tried it?  What was it called with?  What are the data types?

Comment: Or `lptr = str + strlen(str);` (assuming `lptr` and `str` are `char*`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guessing the `str` is a `char*` pointing to a string.

You go through a `for` loop is executed.

1) `lptr = str`, `lptr` starts pointing to the start of the string.

2) `*lptr != '\0'`, checks whether `lptr` has reached the end of string. In C strings are represented as an array of characters terminated by `\0`.

3) `lptr++`, keeps incrementing `lptr` to point to the next character at every iteration. Also checking `*lptr != '\0'` after every iteration.

---

In short, it will go through your string pointed by `str` till the end. Inside the loop you can access the characters one by one as iterations happen, by `*lptr`

Comment: So when the loop is finished, `lptr` will be pointing just past the end of the string (to be precise, it will be pointing at the null terminator character).

Answer (score 2):

This loop starts from pointer to first character of str and goes to next one till it's not pointing to "end of word" - char.

Comment: great answer duo thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no such thing as an "end of word char", one could say end of string, though " terminating null character " is more appropriate.